# how can nightmare upload a image file?

Tags: nightmare

Well.I use nightmare to do some test taskes.It's so good for basing on electron and phatomjs.

Now, I have a question about how can I upload a image file through nightmare?

Well.I find a plugin named [night-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nightmare-upload). After it upload a image file successfully, the page become white and has nothing to show.

So.Is there some solutions to solve this problem?

Comment: I start use this automation library so experience not a lot. One of answer, will can be need add '.end()' after you check code.

Answer (score 2):

Well. The plugin of night-upload can upload a image file through nightmare.

I had write relative path of image file before. So it has the problem as I said: the browser of electron will become white and show nothing, the main process has hang up. Now I change the image file to absolute path. It works!